# se puede realizar un update que es un recalculo por fila que tengan un criterio en común?

Tags: php, mysql, update

estimados me encuentro con una duda, tengo una base de datos que registra la información de vehículos, sus placas, km, fecha del ingreso del km, km anterior, recorrido del vehículo, etc. Y lo que no puedo lograr es que si se ingresa un valor o precio de petróleo en una fecha especifica se actualicen los valores de esa fecha por patente.

lo que sucede con mi programa es que me actualiza la información en la fecha solicitada, pero todos terminan con la misma información de la primera placa, no actualiza por placa.

```
  <label for="" >Ingrese Precio Petroleo y Seleccione Fecha:
  </label>
<form method="post" class="form">
  <input type="text" name="Petro" placeholder="Petroleo">
  <input type="date" name="Fecha_Reg" placeholder="Fecha">
  <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">
</form>
 </center>
  <br>
<center>
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['buscar']))
{
   include("conexion.php");
  $Fecha_Reg = $_POST['Fecha_Reg'];
  $valor = $_POST['Petro'];

  $que = "SELECT Patente, Km_ant, recorrido, Monto FROM Solicitud WHERE Fecha_Reg= 
   '$Fecha_Reg'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $que);


  if($result){
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $ulKm = $row['Km_ant'];
  $rec = $row['recorrido'];
  $Monto = $row['Monto'];
  $Patente = $row['Patente'];
}

  $date = date('w')-0.5;
  $resdate = 6-$date;
  $rendV = 14;

  $carga = 23000;

  $Lt = $carga/$valor;
  $rendC = $Lt*$rendV;


 $recdia = $rec/$date;
 $pro = $recdia*$resdate;
 $difR = $rendC-$rec;
 $saldo = $pro-$difR;
 $monapr=(((($rec/$rendV)/$date)*$resdate)*$valor);
 $difS = $monapr-$Monto;



$rec = "UPDATE Solicitud SET  Monto_apro='$monapr', dif_rec='$difR', sal_carga='$saldo', 
difS='$difS' WHERE Fecha_Reg='$Fecha_Reg'";
$resu =mysqli_query($conexion,$rec);
```

Comment: No veo que especifiques el numero de placa en ningun lugar

Comment: lo que intento es que se actualicen todas las placas que tengan una fecha especifica, ¿te refieres a que tendría que sacar la información de que placas fueron ingresadas en esa fecha primero para poder realizar el update por placa por fecha?

Comment: Estas tomando la primera fila del `SELECT` y luego estas igualando todas las filas con esos valores, lo que necesitas es un bucle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un bucle que itere por las lineas que coincidan con la fecha y luego actualizas cada una de ellas.  Suponiendo que la columna que contiene el numero de placa se llame `placa`, quedaria algo asi:

```
<label for="" >Ingrese Precio Petroleo y Seleccione Fecha:
  </label>
<form method="post" class="form">
  <input type="text" name="Petro" placeholder="Petroleo">
  <input type="date" name="Fecha_Reg" placeholder="Fecha">
  <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">
</form>
 </center>
  <br>
<center>
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['buscar']))
{
   include("conexion.php");
  $Fecha_Reg = $_POST['Fecha_Reg'];
  $valor = $_POST['Petro'];

  $que = "SELECT Patente, Km_ant, recorrido, Monto FROM Solicitud WHERE Fecha_Reg= 
   '$Fecha_Reg'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $que);


  if($result){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  
    $ulKm = $row['Km_ant'];
    $rec = $row['recorrido'];
    $Monto = $row['Monto'];
    $Patente = $row['Patente'];
    
    $date = date('w')-0.5;
    $resdate = 6-$date;
    $rendV = 14;

    $carga = 23000;

    $Lt = $carga/$valor;
    $rendC = $Lt*$rendV;

   $recdia = $rec/$date;
   $pro = $recdia*$resdate;
   $difR = $rendC-$rec;
   $saldo = $pro-$difR;
   $monapr=(((($rec/$rendV)/$date)*$resdate)*$valor);
   $difS = $monapr-$Monto;
   $placa = $row['placa'];   
    
  $rec = "UPDATE Solicitud SET  Monto_apro='$monapr', dif_rec='$difR', sal_carga='$saldo', 
difS='$difS' WHERE Fecha_Reg='$Fecha_Reg' and placa='$placa'";
$resu =mysqli_query($conexion,$rec);
}
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha funcionado, el único cambio que he realizado de tu programación es que mysql_fetch_assoc ya no funciona, ahora es mysqli_fetch_assoc